# How do I select data from one table where column values from that table match the conatenated column values of another table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database-design

Table customers

```
id     fName        lName      pNumber
 1     Adeline      Brown      55512300
 2     May          Green      55512094
```

Table accounting

```
id     customerName       datePaid        amount
1      Brown, Adeline     2012-08-09      210
2      Green, May         2012-09-09      430
```

My problem is how do I select the `pNumber` based on the `datePaid` corresponding to `customerName`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should remove the `customerName` from the Accounting table, and replace it with the `CustomerId`. But, for now, you can `JOIN` the two tables using any predicate as the `JOIN` condition, something like this:

```
SELECT c.pNumber
FROM Customers c
INNER JOIN accounting ac ON c.fName + ', ' + p.lName = ac.customerName
```

The problem with your table `Accouting` structure, is that, it *isn't* [**normalized**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), especially, doesn't meet the third normal form ***3NF*** which is:

> **3NF:** Eliminate Columns not dependant on the key

The column `customerName` in the `Accounting` table doesn't depend on the accounting `id` of that table. So, your tables should look like:

**Customers** table:

- `id`, `fName`, `lName`, `pNumber`.

**accounting** table:

- `id`, `customerId` foreign key references `Customers(Id)`, `datePaid`, `amount`.

Then you can `JOIN` the two tables directly `ON customerId` which will improve the performance very much:

```
SELECT c.pNumber
FROM Customers c
INNER JOIN accounting ac ON c.Id = ac.CustomerId
```

**Edit:** Nothing wrong in your query. May be you haven't any rows that match this condition. You can try the following query it is the same as what you wrote, but it more organized:

```
SELECT c.pNumber 
FROM customers c 
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT id, customerName, datePaid, amount
        TO_DAYS(DATE(datePaid)) - TO_DAYS(CURDATE()) AS DaysFromPayment
    FROM Accounting 
) ac ON c.last_name + ', ' + c.first_name = ac.customerName 
WHERE ac.DaysFromPayment = 30
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You've been a great help. Shouldn't have zoned out when Database Normalization was taught :) Something new to go and learn properly.

Comment: Sorry to be a bother, I just noticed that it lists every single number three times. Why is it happening?

Comment: `SELECT  c.pNumber 
FROM  customers  c 
INNER JOIN  accounting  ac ON  c.last_name +  ', ' +  c.first_name =  ac.customerName`

Comment: @ThisBoyPerforms Thats many customers had many accountings in the `Accounting` table, so your query returns many `customerName` from the second table `Accounting` table. To solve this use `DISTINCT` add it before the `c.pNumber`. And if any thing goes wrong don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: I think I would in the future, normalize my databases. Already started reading up on them, and they are looking good and learn-able.

Comment: Yes you should. And then you will find out that your queries will be much more easy to write and easy to read. Let me suggest if you really want to read more in this subject, that you began with the great book [Database Design for Mere Mortals: A Hands-On Guide to Relational Database Design](http://www.amazon.com/Database-Design-Mere-Mortals-Relational/dp/0201694719) and the other book of the same series [SQL Queries for Mere Mortals: A Hands-On Guide to Data Manipulation in SQL](http://www.amazon.com/SQL-Queries-Mere-Mortals-Manipulation/dp/0321444434/ref=pd_sim_b_4/180-9027754-3805744)

Comment: Funny enough, I have a copy of the first one. It was a recommended text. I'll go and dust it and start reading it.

Comment: One more thing, I added a `WHERE` clause to it. It didn't work. I did `WHERE TO_DAYS(DATE(ac.datePaid)) - TO_DAYS(CURDATE()) = 30`

Comment: @ThisBoyPerforms, Post the query please. And what do you mean by didn't work? Is there any error? or it doesn't return the expected result?

Comment: It didn't filter it as it was supposed to. No errors. Whether the `WHERE` clause is there or not, the same results are returned

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT c.pNumber FROM customers c INNER JOIN accounting ac ON c.last_name + ', ' + c.first_name = ac.customerName WHERE TO_DAYS(DATE(ac.datePaid)) - TO_DAYS(CURDATE()) = 30`

Comment: It's not as if it isn't giving me any rows. Problem is, it is giving me EVERY row. The `WHERE` clause is supposed to filter it based on the specified conditions.

Comment: @ThisBoyPerforms, Sorry I can't see anything wrong in your query. But you can start a new question with that and be clear, and describe the question well with some sample data that doesn't work.